# how to enable CUDA in ZED Orin Box

Tags: nvidia-jetson

I am using ZED X Camera along with ZED ORIN BOX which has Jetpack SDK pre installed. As I went through the documentation I saw that CUDA also comes along with the SDK Manager but I was unable to use GPU on running inferences for an object detection model using YOLO. Please give me a detailed step of how to re install or enable GPU access ie CUDA and CUDNN in ZED ORIN BOX that has Jetson.

I tried to reset the box but I was unable to do it.